# What does $ y=f(x)>0$ really mean? do we have to choose the domain where $f(x)>0$ or does it mean something else?

Tags: integration

Statement : The area bounded by one of the arcs of $y = cos(ax)$ and $X$-axis is $2/a$ sq units

Reason: The area bounded by $y = f(x) > 0$ and $y = 0$ between $x=a$ and $x=b$ is $∫_a^b f(x)dx$

a) Both Statement and Reason are correct and the reason explains the statement

b) Both Statement and Reason are correct but the reason does not explain the statement

c) Statement is valid but the Reason is false

d) Reason is valid but the Statement is false

1.My main doubt is that is the reason valid for $cos(ax)$ as well?

2.The more fundamental doubt i have is that does the statement $y = f(x) > 0$ mean we have to CHOOSE WHERE $f(x)>0$ or does it mean that $f(x)$ is such a function that it is perpetually greater than $0$?

3.And finally, does the reason explain the assertion?

My reasoning is that $y = f(x)>0$ means that for all x, y is always greater than 0 that is the function always lies above the x-axis when graphed. Then, the integration of any $2$ points from $a$ to $b$ between the function and the x-axis is simply $∫_a^b f(x)dx$. However, this does not fit the function $cos(ax)$ as $cos(ax)$ is not always positive for all values of $x$. So i cant justify that the reason the correct explanation of the assertion

However,the answer to this question is option a, which i am not able to understand as to why it is correct and where my understanding is wrong. Please help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of $f(x)>0$ as a restriction; $f(x)$ has to be positive within its domain. If you choose $f(x)=\cos(ax)$ in the domain $x\in[-\frac\pi{2a},\frac\pi{2a}]$, then you will see that $f(x)$ is always positive, and as such, we can apply the second part of the reasoning, that to find the area bound by $y=f(x)>0$ and $y=0$ from $x=a$ to $x=b$, you can do $\int_a^bf(x)dx$. In this case, we will take the following integral:
$$\int_{-\frac\pi{2a}}^{\frac\pi{2a}}\cos(ax)dx$$
which you can compute yourself to be $2/a$.

Answer (score 0):

I have not really thought about whether answer a) makes sense, but I think I can answer two of your questions that are mainly concerned with the language:

> However, this does not fit the function cos(ax) as cos(ax) is not
> always positive for all values of x.

I would interpret the phrase "one of the arcs" to mean the graph of $\cos(ax)$ restricted to the interval between two successive zeros of $\cos(ax)$. Then you have either $\cos(ax)\geq 0$ for all $x$ or $\cos(ax)\leq 0$ for all $x$ in that interval, and it is more or less obvious that the area is the same in both cases.

> The more fundamental doubt i have is that does the statement "y = f(x) > 0"
> mean we have to CHOOSE WHERE f(x)>0 or does it mean that f(x) is such a function that it is perpetually greater than 0?

It's just an assumption on $f$. If you have $f(x)>0$ everywhere, then the area is given by the integral.